# How can you add something in the right click menu in nautilus so that it copies to a certain directory?

Tags: nautilus, copy, context-menu, nautilus-actions

I'm trying to add a menu entry onto the right-click menu of nautilus so that it copies selected files from their current directory to another. Essentially I want it to run a program / command that is like:`sudo cp -i -a <Selected files in current directory> /path/to/my/folder` I have installed nautilus-actions but I am struggling to use it. Or, even better, if I could make a .deb package or something that I can install on other computers without using nautilus-actions.

Cheers

Comment: Okay, I've found a thing in nautilus-actions that lets me have the command outside of the nautilus-actions subfolder. Still wondering how I can turn this into an installable .deb package though.

Answer (score 0):

As of 16.04 LTS , the Nautilus version `3.14.3` has `Copy To` and `Move To` options

[image]